# Debugging occasional "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: postfix, bind, spf

I have an internet-connected mailserver. A friend wants to send Email to one of the hosted domains.

occasionally smtpd reports:

```
Jun 24 00:56:22 myserver postfix/smtpd[xxx]: warning: hostname e2i740.smtp2go.com does not resolve to address 103.2.142.228: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

And this results in an SPF failure:

```
Jun 24 00:56:23 myserver policyd-spf[xxx]: 550 5.7.23 Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized. Please see http://www.openspf.net/Why?s=helo;id=e2i740.smtp2go.com;ip=103.2.142.228;r=<UNKNOWN>
```

Now... The first happening isn't a surefire cause for the second: I got a Paypal message ("You've got money!" yey!) and that one got through SPF just fine.

I've searched the internet, and solutions indicated are things like: check your resolv.conf. I've checked, it looks ok, it works in at least 99% of cases, so that's not it.

I have already told SPF to treat temporary nameserver errors as nonfatal (return 4xx-defer), but that didn't help.

As usual I am inclined to think it is probably the other guys who have an unreliable connection/nameserver. But I'd like a bit better proof than "just a hunch"....

The "enable bind debugging on ubuntu" howtos seem to "not work" for me. (nameserver throws an error and refuses to start up).

Comment: The error message contains already both a name and an IP address, so the resolution failure is probably on the PTR record. Otherwise based on https://dnsviz.net/d/e2i740.smtp2go.com/Yrmu4w/dnssec/ the name is in a lame delegation status which is never good and a typicaly source of "temporary failures in resolution". Same for reverse tree in fact: https://dnsviz.net/d/228.142.2.103.in-addr.arpa/YrmvTA/dnssec/

Comment: *"told SPF to treat temporary nameserver errors as nonfatal"* what!? Any software dealing with SPF should, by default, be correctly setup to deal with *transient errors*. Please detail your SPF setup and DNS configuration, which probably both offer configuration to increase log verbosity.

Comment: @arix: /etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf has TempError_Defer = False on Ubuntu 18.04 . I changed it to true. @ Patrick: I've bounced the problem to the smtp2go user. He should complain to them that their bad DNS is causing issues for him. He's a paying customer.